# How to reduce the temporary table expiration time in BigQuery

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

We run `Spark` jobs which access `BigQuery`. During read phase, data is being pulled from a temporary table with naming convention `_sbc_*`. By default, the table exipration is **24 hours**. But for our usecase, retention period of **1 hour** is more than enough. I was wondering is there any we can bring down the temporary table expiration duration from 24 hours to 1 hour.

Below is how we instantiate `spark config`,

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf
   sparkConf.setAppName("test-app")
   sparkConf.setMaster("local[*]")
   sparkConf.set("viewsEnabled", "true")
   sparkConf.set("parentProject", "<parentProject>")
   sparkConf.set("materializationProject", "<materializationProject>")
   sparkConf.set("materializationDataset", "<materializationDataset>")
   sparkConf.set("credentials", "<credentials>")
```

**Note:** Temporary table is getting created in project passed for `materializationProject` parameter.

Spark version : `spark-2.3.1`

Answer (score 3):

As of 2023-01-13, there now appears to be an option called `materializationExpirationTimeInMinutes` that defines the temporary table expiration time.  If not set, it defaults to 24 hours.

See [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector).

Answer (score 1):

`spark-bigquery-connector` doesn't provide any option to set expiration time over the materialized views it creates during reading.

However, if you're using a specific `materializationDataset` for these jobs, you can directly define the [default expiration time for that dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-datasets#table-expiration) in BigQuery. It will be applied to all tables and views created under the dataset.

```
bq update --default_table_expiration 3600 materializationProject:materializationDataset
```